# Flutter | Streamed http.client.send not receiving any response all in sudden

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Here's my method, which has been working well till yesterday without any issue. Broke all in sudden today for few hours... Worked well again for few hours & is broken again. Don't know what could have went wrong.. Does someone see a problem in this method ? Any alternative best recommendations ???

PS : Internet was connected & that's affirmative.

```
Future<Stream<Product>> getProducts() async {
  print("Entering getProducts..");
  Uri uri = Helper.getUri('api/products');
  try {
    final client = new http.Client();
    print("Going to stream..")  // --> Prints this line..
    final streamedRest = await client.send(http.Request('get', uri));
     print("Done streaming..")  // --> Didn't print this at all...PROBLEMM
    return streamedRest.stream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(json.decoder)
        .map((data) => Helper.getData(data))
        .expand((data) => (data as List))
        .map((data) {
      return Product.fromJSON(data);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error while gathering products...product_repo");
    print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: uri.toString()).toString());
    return new Stream.value(new Product.fromJSON({}));
  }
}
```

Comment: did it go to catch?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes... that's what is happening for now..

Comment: What it print in the catch?

Comment: @JohnJoe What do you expect when i say it print the catch.. ? 

"Error while gathering products...product_repo" & my URI to string... its evident from my code right ?

Comment: `print(e.toString);`